# Promisify Socket.IO / EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, promise

I am a bit surprised by the fact that I don't find much when googling for Promisify Socket.IO. Is it that uncommon?

I also had troubles to promisify it myself:

```
Promise.promisifyAll(io)
io.onceAsync('connect')
.then((socket) => ...)
.catch((err) => console.log(error))
```

This always triggers the error case, I assume because `.once` is a callback with only one argument, where Promises expect the first one to be the error. Any idea how to deal with these kind of things?

Comment: What Google did you use? https://github.com/kriskowal/q-connection

Comment: yeah, native socket.io please

Answer (score 28):

I can think of several reasons why promises aren't a good fit with socket.io and `EventEmitter` interfaces in general:

1. For the most part, socket.io is an event driven interface and promises do not align architecturally with events that can occur more than once (since a promise is a one-shot device).  Yes, you can use a promise for `.connect()`, but not for incoming messages.  So, most people (myself included) probably don't think it makes sense to have half an interface using promises and the other half using event handlers.  Likely better to use one model for the whole API.
2. `Promise.promisifyAll()` requires node.js style async callbacks (with error value as the first argument and data as the second argument) and that isn't what any of the socket.io event handler callbacks use.  To make promises work with something like the `connect` event you'd have to write your own custom promsification which is likely more work than just using the event handler it is written for.

An exception to the above might be if you are trying to coordinate the next occurrence of an event with other async events (something that isn't usually done) in which case promises might be useful for the coordination.  As an example, supposed you wanted to know when three separate asynchronous operations were all complete, one of which was the next occurrence of a socket.io event.  Then, it might make sense to manually promisify that event so you could use promises to coordinate your multiple async operations.

But for normal socket.io usage, promises just aren't a good architectural fit.  Similarly, you wouldn't typically use promises for a click handler in a web page.

---

FYI, if you want to promisify just the `connect` operation, you could do that manually like this:

```
io.connectAsync = function(url, options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        io.connect(url, options);
        io.once('connect', function(socket) {
            resolve(socket);
        });
        io.once('connect_error', function() {
            reject(new Error('connect_error'));
        });
        io.once('connect_timeout', function() {
            reject(new Error('connect_timeout'));
        });
    });
}


io.connectAsync().then(function(socket) {
    // connected here
    socket.on('someMsg', function() {
       // process message here
    });
}, function(err) {
    // error connecting here
});
```

Comment: @Mahoni - Did this answer your question? If so, please click the green checkmark to the left of the answer to indicate that to the community and to earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure here on stack overflow.  If not, please explain what part of your question is not answered.

Comment: The listeners inside the promise must be `once` type. Otherwise you will have multiple calls to resolve or reject on reconnections.

Comment: @Hkan - Additional calls to resolve or reject are ignored because a promise can only be resolved or rejected once.

Comment: Oh, I thought it would throw an exception. My bad - I should've checked before commenting.

Comment: @jfriend00 You should still use .once, otherwise you might cause a memory leak. Especially if the function where called many times.

Comment: @youngwerth - I don't see any memory leak issue here.  Can you expand on that?  There's no issue with an event listener on an object that otherwise has no references.  It will still be garbage collected.  In other words, you don't have to remove all event listeners for something to be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @jfriend00 The object is referenced by the emitter itself. The function lives and is called as long as the emitter is live. EventEmitters can accumulate listeners over time. This is a common memory leak. Node.js will even warn you of the possible memory leak if you exceed a certain amount of listeners.

Comment: @youngwerth - I get your generic argument, but where do you think the potential leak is here?  `io` is the eventEmitter itself and the only thing it has a reference to is a callback function and it can't cause a leak by having a reference to itself.

Comment: @jfriend00 As long as `io` exists there will be three new listeners every time its `connectAsync` function is called. So `io` may grow over time as `connectAsync` is called. In this case as I doubt `connectAsync` is called very often during `io`'s lifetime. So it's not likely to be a major memory leak. But it depends on the use case.

Comment: @youngwerth - That's fair.  Edited.

Comment: Only problem here being that function `io.once()` does not exist at all if you use `socket.io-client` library for the connection... ;)

Comment: Actually with quite a few changes to your code I was able to get it running.
Basically, inside the Promise code:

`let socket = io.connect(url, options);`

and then
`socket.once('connect', ....`

This got the ball rolling.

Comment: i executed the same above code but I'm getting `once is not a function` in the event `connect` . please check the code again.

Comment: @Alexander - That sounds like you're using the wrong thing for `io`.

Comment: i just wrote the code same as @kyeno mentioned in the comment previous to mine

Comment: @Alexander - If you want further help with your specific situation, you will need to write your own question and show your actual code.

Comment: @jfriend00 no I don't have. Thanks for your answers related to socket io in this platform, they were really helpful.