# How to send data when connecting to server in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

In `socket.io` client side javascript, I connect like this

```
var socket = new io();
```

then I send data to server like this

```
socket.emit('start', data);
```

But I want to send data asap to the server with a promise that it was received. How can I do that? I was hoping there was something like this

```
var socket = new io(null, data, function(data) {
    // data was received on server and server responded with complete
    // data is 'ok'
});
```

node.js

```
var io = socket.listen(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket, data) {
    socket.emit('ok');
});
```

What's the closest I can do something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365268/promisify-socket-io-eventemitter) looks like it might be a good answer to your question, along with some sample code as to how you could do it manually anyway. The short version seems to be that the model of promises just doesn't work with `EventEmitters`. Hope this helps!