# Streams interrupts at the wrong time NodeJS when downloading multiple images

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am trying to write to disk multiple images concurrently in NodeJS, wait for them all to be done and then continue with the execution of my program.
Here is my code :

```js
const Router = require('express-promise-router');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const router = new Router();
const axios = require("axios");
var Promise = require('bluebird')
// export our router to be mounted by the parent application
module.exports = router;

async function downloadImage(folder, url, username) {
    const filePath = path.resolve(folder, username + '.jpg');
    const writer = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);

    const response = await axios({
        url,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'stream'
    });

    response.data.pipe(writer);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        writer.on('end', resolve(username));
        writer.on('error', reject("error"));
    });
}

router.post('/download_photos', (req, res, next) => {

    let input = [
        {username: "a_S", "image_path": "http://sr.photos2.fotosearch.com/bthumb/CSP/CSP992/k14639982.jpg"},
        {username: "b_L1", "image_path": "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/example-stamp-28420393.jpg"},
        {username: "c_L2", "image_path": "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/example-red-stamp-text-white-43363006.jpg"},
        {username: "d_S", "image_path": "http://sr.photos2.fotosearch.com/bthumb/CSP/CSP992/k14639982.jpg"},
        {username: "e_L2", "image_path": "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/example-red-stamp-text-white-43363006.jpg"},
        {username: "f_L2", "image_path": "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/example-red-stamp-text-white-43363006.jpg"},
        {username: "g_S", "image_path": "http://sr.photos2.fotosearch.com/bthumb/CSP/CSP992/k14639982.jpg"},
        {username: "h_L3", "image_path": "https://www.goldsteinlegal.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Brand-stock-image.jpg"},
        {username: "i_L3", "image_path": "https://www.goldsteinlegal.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Brand-stock-image.jpg"} ,
        {username: "j_L3", "image_path": "https://www.goldsteinlegal.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Brand-stock-image.jpg"}                   ,
    ];

    let folderPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), "images", "test");
    fs.rmdirSync(folderPath, {recursive: true})
    fs.mkdirSync(folderPath);

    Promise.map(input, (x) => {
            let image_path = x.image_path;
            if (image_path !== "") {
                return downloadImage(folderPath, x.image_path, x.username)
                    .then((res) => x.username)
                    .catch((err) => err);
            }
        },
        {concurrency: 100})
        .then((images) => {
            res.send("OK");
        })
        .catch((err) => res.status(400).send(err));
});
```

I would have expected the `"OK"` to be sent only once all the downloading was done. But in fact the server sends back `"OK"` but the downloading is still happening in the background. (It might not look like it when you execute the code on a fast connection, but try it with a lot more images or much larger ones and the issue should become obvious).

How do I modify that code so that it gets to the `res.send("OK")` line only when all images are actually done downloading ?

Comment: `writer.on('end', resolve(username));` does not attach an event handler, but immediately calls the `resolve` function

Comment: Thanks but I'm a newbie (as you might have noticed :) ). How should I modify the code so that it does what I've described ?

Comment: `await new Promise((resolve, reject) => { writer.on('end', resolve); writer.on('error', reject); }); return username;`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/40707812/1048572, https://stackoverflow.com/q/37365268/1048572 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/43084615/1048572

Comment: thanks for the links will have a look. Using your modification, I can see that it downloads everythig but it does not ever continue the execution then i.e never reaches the `res.send("OK")`

Comment: Do the individual promises (that are returned by `downloadImage`) fulfill?

Comment: I'm not sure how to test that tbh. A breakpoint within the `then` of `return downloadImage(folderPath, x.image_path, x.username).then((res) => x.username).catch((err) => err);` never gets activated.

Comment: and the `return username;` within `downloadImage` is never reached either.

Comment: AH! the writable stream event should be `finish` and not `end` in the async function !

Comment: If you want to write an answer I'll validate it. Otherwise I'll post it myself tomorrow for information purposes in case it helps someone. In any case thank you very much.